# Edited build.prop of HCl me sync 1.0

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, root-access, file-system, boot-loop

I recently rooted my HCl me sync 1.0(u3)  and changed the build.prop to download some unsupported app. But when I rebooted the tab it stuck in a bootloop(with the screen orientation changed). I have a copy of original build.prop in my memory card. I have no custom recovery.please help me anyone

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to restore/edit build.prop after rebooting (and phone stuck in reboot loop)?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/63585/how-to-restore-edit-build-prop-after-rebooting-and-phone-stuck-in-reboot-loop). Also see https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/80875/im-stuck-in-a-bootloop-after-editing-build-prop-system-files-ive-tried-everythin

Comment: Have you tried a factory reset from the standard recovery?

Comment: @Matthew Read Yes but that does not effect system files